# AJAX Post to .PHP to JSON Data-set || PHP File

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

Afternoon guys/gals,

I'm relatively new to using AJAX to POST information to a JSON file and I am not sure what the .php file should look like to process it. I have very little experience with .php. Am I on the right track?  I've looked a lot of examples but most of them only have pieces of the .php file to process it.  I am trying to inject the "task" into the JSON file which I then use handlebars to read on another page.

```
  function fnCreateTask() {
        var url = "save.php";
        var title = $("#TaskTitle").val();
        var date = $("#TaskDate").val();
        var desc = $("#TaskDescription").val();

        var info = {
            Title: title,
            Date: date,
            Description: desc
        };

        var body = JSON.stringify(info);

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: url,
            contentType: 'application/json',
            data: body,
            dataType: 'json',
            error: function (err) {console.log(err)},
            success: function (data) {
                alert('Task Created.');
                location.reload();
            }
        });
    } 


<?php
    $fp = fopen('careers.json', 'w');
    fwrite($fp, $_POST = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true););
    fclose($fp);
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$.ajax POST (or GET for that matter) data will be x-form encoded by default when sent to the server. You can do

on the client

```
//object for the data
var data = {
              title: $("#TaskTitle").val(),
              date: $("#TaskDate").val()
};     

$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "save.php",
        data: data,
        error: function (err) {console.log(err)},
        success: function (data) {
            alert('Task Created.');
            location.reload();
        }
    });
```

and on the server

```
    // as a separate object to be safe
    $dataobj['title'] = $_POST['title'];
    $dataobj['date'] = $_POST['date'];

    // write json_encode object to file
    file_put_contents ( 'filename.json' , json_encode($dataobj));
```

Answer (score 0):

To create a JSON in PHP :

```
<?php
$array = array(
        "name" => "toto",
        "lastname" => "lafraise",
        "age" => 33
);
$fp = fopen('careers.json', 'w');
fwrite($fp, json_encode($array));
fclose($fp);
```

Comment: I already have the .json file and does this take what was in my form and inject it into the .json file?